# Heroku push fails: Error: `libsass` bindings not found. Try reinstalling `node-sass`?

Tags: heroku, ember.js, libsass

I'm trying to push a new app to Heroku but I'm getting this libsass error:

`Error: ´libsass´ bindings not found. Try reinstalling ´node-sass´?`

I've looked all around but the solutions I've found are for a local environment, but I have no problem on my machine.

One of the things I found was to use node 0.12.0, I was on 0.10, but Heroku is already on 0.12.0

What else can I do on Heroku?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have `node-sass` in your `package.json` if so setting `NODE_MODULES_CACHE` to false may help

You can do it on heroku.com or in CLI:

`heroku config:set NODE_MODULES_CACHE=false`